# Replace Value of Variable in Query

Tags: php

currently i have `page1.php` being entered into the URL bar with the variable status and a string in the URL like this `http://example.com/page1.php?status=red`. When the user clicks enter, it redirects to `page2.php` and generates more variables and adds another `&status=` at the end of the url like this `http://example.com/page2.php?status=red&varone=1&vartwo=2&status=green`

Instead of having 2 status variables in the URL, i would like to remove the 1st 1 completely so it is just left with `&status=green` at the end.

Here is the code I have for the header redirect:

```
$query = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
header("Location: page2.php" . $query . "&status=" . $currentstatus);
```

I would rather remove the first `?status=` if possible, since i do want `&status=` at the very end of the url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP add/modify a query string param & get the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892817/php-add-modify-a-query-string-param-get-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove first occurrence of status from query string then better to remove it from the previous URL.

Answer (score 0):

try if status is the only parameter:

```
 $query= str_replace("status=".$_REQUEST["status"],"", $query);
```

or if there are more following:

```
$query= str_replace("status=".$_REQUEST["status"]."&","", $query);
```

Comment: this would not work with the example because status was the only parameter passed, thus no trailing &.  You could use a regular expression to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query     = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$new_query = str_replace($_REQUEST['status'], $currentstatus, $query); // New query with $currentstatus as status value

header("Location: page2.php?" . $new_query);
```

Comment: this would not work if there was another string that contained the status' string.

Comment: In general, it replace all status parameters. It will be work  fine based on op's current requirement and parameters using.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace` option : (note, this will not work if the parameter doesn't yet exist)

```
$query = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$query= preg_replace("/status=".$_REQUEST["status"]."(&)?/","status=$currentstatus$1", $query);
header("Location: page2.php" . $query);
```

`parse_str` option : (this will work even if the parameter does not yet exist)

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);
$query['status'] = $currentstatus;
header("Location: page2.php" . http_build_query($query_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

user `parse_str` and `http_build_query`. try below solution:

```
$query_string = 'status=red&varone=1&vartwo=2';
$current_status = 'newstatus';

//parse current query string
parse_str($query_string, $q_arr);

//replace new status
$q_arr['status'] = $current_status;

//generate new query string
$new_query_string = http_build_query($q_arr);
```

**output**

```
status=newstatus&varone=1&vartwo=2
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to treat the query string like a string. You get the variables in PHP as a nice array, so use it!

```
$_GET["status"] = $currentstatus;
$query = http_build_query($_GET);
header("Location: page2.php?$query");
```